# Flask Sqlalchemy, field does not have a default value

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

So, I'm trying to create database models for a shopping cart for users.

Here are the models that i'm using:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    ...
    cart = db.relationship('Cart', backref='user', uselist=False)

class Cart(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    ...

class ProductCartAssociation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    cart_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cart.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id'), primary_key=True)

    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=1)

    product = db.relationship('Product', backref=db.backref('cart_association'))
    cart = db.relationship('Cart', backref=db.backref('product_association'))
```

Essentially, each user has a one-to-one relationship with a cart and then since there is a many-to-many relationship between a cart and a product i created the **ProductCartAssociation** model which is meant to act as an **association object** to link these two together.

The problem that I'm having is that upon performing the following lines of code I get the following error:

```
u=User.query.get(1)
c=Cart()
u.cart=c
db.session.add(c)
db.session.commit()
p1=Product.query.get(1)
association=ProductCartAssociation()
association.product=p1
c.product_association.append(association)
```

Upon executing the last line i get the following error:

```
Column 'association.cart_id' is marked as a member of the primary key for table 'association',
 but has no Python-side or server-side default generator indicated, nor does it indicate
 'autoincrement=True' or 'nullable=True', and no explicit value is passed.  Primary key columns typically
 may not store NULL. Note that as of SQLAlchemy 1.1, 'autoincrement=True' must be indicated explicitly
 for composite (e.g. multicolumn) primary keys if AUTO_INCREMENT/SERIAL/IDENTITY behavior is expected
 for one of the columns in the primary key. CREATE TABLE statements are impacted by this change as well on most backends.
    
    ...
    
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1364, "Field 'cart_id' doesn't have a default value")
[SQL: INSERT INTO association (product_id, quantity) VALUES (%(product_id)s, %(quantity)s)]
```

The first part of the error says that I had to set auto_increment to true for the cart_id column of my ProductCartAssociation table. This is not correct as I'm providing foreign keys as its values, thus these cannot get set (according to: [sqlalchemy association object - composite primary key and existing object issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360410/sqlalchemy-association-object-composite-primary-key-and-existing-object-issue))

I'm really stuck on this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that a normal way to do a `many-to-many` relationship? I thought the way to do that was with an association table as shown [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html)

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object   Towards the bottom of the link it states that if you need additional columns inside of your association table you need to use the so called "Association object". And based on the information on the documentation, mine should work which is why I can't wrap my head around the error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an existing model instance to an association object, you can set the foreign key field (and more importantly in this case, part of the primary key) explicitly.

```
# ...
p1 = Product.query.get(1)
association = ProductCartAssociation()
association.product_id = p1.id
c.product_association.append(association)
```

Comment: You've got it backwards. The product_id is being set thanks to `association.product=p1` (obvious from the log output), but the autoflush triggered by accessing the relationship `c.product_association`, which issues a  lazyload query, is the reason why the half finished association is being flushed before having a cart set.

Comment: @IljaEverilä you're right, I mixed it up. Strangely enough, it works for me when I do it the way I described in my answer.